# Finding mid-point date between two dates in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

Given dates:

```
my_guess = '2014-11-30'
their_guess = '2017-08-30'
```

How do I split the delta between the dates, returning the correct calendar date?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One way would be to use `datetime`. Find the difference between two dates, halve it, and add it on the earlier date:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = datetime(2014, 11, 30)
>>> b = datetime(2017, 8 ,30)
>>> a + (b - a)/2
2016-04-15 00:00:00
```

Comment: This not only works with `datetime` objects, but with `date` objects as well (tested in Python 3.5)

Comment: Just an FYI, know it's been 6 years, but this is not working as expected in Python 3.9 - the result of `a + (b - a)/2` is just the value of a for me.

Comment: I had the error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.datetime'` any idea why?

Comment: Ok, I said... `a + (b - a)/2` is the same as `(a + b) / 2`... well it is not...

Comment: @AgustinBarrachina: Python doesn't allow you to add `datetime` objects: you need `datetime + timedelta` (subtracting `datetime` objects gives you a `timedelta` object).

Comment: @ThePartyTurtle: this method still works for me (I tried in Python 3.10): if you have an example where it produces an incorrect result please let me know values for `a` and `b` and I will investigate.

Answer (score 5):

```
from datetime import datetime
d1 = datetime.strptime(my_guess,"%Y-%m-%d")
d2 = datetime.strptime(their_guess,"%Y-%m-%d")
print d1.date() + (d2-d1) / 2 # first date plus the midpoint of the difference between d1 and d2  
2016-04-15
```