# Plotly: How to label bars on a gantt chart?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, gantt-chart

Is there any way to create in Plotly Gantt chart with Task labels on bars and Resource labels on y-axis?

There is no such example in [documentation](https://plot.ly/python/gantt/) of `plotly.figure_factory.create_gantt`. An abstract example of desirable chart is presented below:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add annotations structured as a list of dictionaries in `fig['layout']['annotations']` based on a setup like the first example from [your link](https://plot.ly/python/gantt/).

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

The structure of the plot is similar to the source above, but I've set it up to work with `iplot()` in an off-line Jupyter Notebook.

```
# imports
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# setup
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:50% !important; } .widget-select > select {background-color: gainsboro;}</style>"))
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

#%qtconsole --style vim

# dates
StartA = '2009-01-01'
StartB = '2009-03-05'
StartC = '2009-02-20'

FinishA='2009-02-28'
FinishB='2009-04-15'
FinishC='2009-05-30'

LabelDateA='2009-01-25'
LabelDateB='2009-03-20'
LabelDateC='2009-04-01'

# sample data
df = [dict(Task="Task A", Start=StartA, Finish=FinishA),
      dict(Task="Task B", Start=StartB, Finish=FinishB),
      dict(Task="Task C", Start=StartC, Finish=FinishC)]

# figure
fig = ff.create_gantt(df)

# add annotations
annots =  [dict(x=LabelDateA,y=0,text="Task label A", showarrow=False, font=dict(color='white')),
           dict(x=LabelDateB,y=1,text="Task label B", showarrow=False, font=dict(color='White')),
           dict(x=LabelDateC,y=2,text="Task label C", showarrow=False, font=dict(color='White'))]

# plot figure
fig['layout']['annotations'] = annots
iplot(fig)
```

**Possible improvements:**

As you can see, I've hard-coded the dates where the labels are positioned. You could just as easily [calculate the middle date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473394/finding-mid-point-date-between-two-dates-in-python) between the start and end dates. But why not simply adjust the labels using `align=center` in `(x=LabelDateC,y=2,align="center",text="Task label C", showarrow=False, font=dict(color='White'))`? That won't work because the label seems to be attached to the dates itself and not the structure or size of the bar.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helps a lot. The only small problem now is that I want to combine such annotations with `group_tasks = True` option, which reverse the ordering of "Task" categories along y-axis: for example when `group_Tasks = False` categories "Job-1" are located at the bottom and "Job-4" - at the top.   With `group_Tasks = True` situation is the opposite: one "joined" "Job-1" at the top. Do you know if there is any way to fix it?