# Pandas Convert Dictionary to List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to use Plotly Gantt and add annotations to the view, but am running into issues with adding the annotations. My data is being pulled from a dataframe where the label is df['Label'] (string), but I made a test dataframe 'ann' and had no luck with it below. It looks like the list of dictionaries that they are using has an = inbetween while mine is a : - is that what's causing the issue? Any easy fix? I can't label all of the annotations individually like it is below because there are hundreds

Sample of correct format:

```
annots =  [dict(x=LabelDateA,y=0,text="Task label A", showarrow=False, font=dict(color='white')),
           dict(x=LabelDateB,y=1,text="Task label B", showarrow=False, font=dict(color='White')),
           dict(x=LabelDateC,y=2,text="Task label C", showarrow=False, font=dict(color='White'))]
REF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56066052/plotly-gantt-chart
```

Error:

```
ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'builtins.dict_values' received for the 'annotations' property of layout
        Received value: dict_values([{'x': Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'), 'y': 2, 'text': 'test', 'showarrow': False}, {'x': Timestamp('2020-07-01 00:00:00'), 'y': 5, 'text': 'test3', 'showarrow': False}])

    The 'annotations' property is a tuple of instances of
    Annotation that may be specified as:
      - A list or tuple of instances of plotly.graph_objs.layout.Annotation
      - A list or tuple of dicts of string/value properties that
        will be passed to the Annotation constructor
```

Code:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# figure
fig = ff.create_gantt(df)

# add annotations
annots =  [dict(x=LabelDateA,y=0,text="Task label A", showarrow=False, font=dict(color='white')),
           dict(x=LabelDateB,y=1,text="Task label B", showarrow=False, font=dict(color='White')),
           dict(x=LabelDateC,y=2,text="Task label C", showarrow=False, font=dict(color='White'))]

print(df)

ann = ann.T.to_dict().values()
print(ann)

# plot figure
fig['layout']['annotations'] = ann
fig.show()
```

Comment: use ``to_dict(orient='records')`` on pandas dataframe.

Comment: Not sure if that is working... The resulting dictionary still contains : rather than = and is outputting the same error. I also had to remove the .values() portion when adding the orient